# Threading model for high capacity Java server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client-server

I'm creating a Java server for a quite big simulation and I have a couple of high level design questions.

### Some background:

- The server will run a simulation.
- Clients will connect to the server via TCP connections from mobile devices and interact with data structures in the simulation. Initially I will try to use a simple polling scheme in the clients. I find it hard to maintain long-lived TCP connections between mobile devices and the server and I'm not yet sure whether the clients will try to keep an open TCP connection or whether they will set it up and tear it down for each transmission.
- When a client is active on a mobile device, I would like to have the client poll the server at least a few times a minute.
- The simulation will keep running regardless of whether clients are connected or not.
- The total number of existing clients could get very large, many thousands.
- Clients mostly poll the server for simulation state, but also sometimes issues control commands to the simulation.
- All messages are small in size.
- I expect the server to run under Linux on multi-core CPU server hardware.

### Currently I have the following idea for threading model in the server:

- The simulation logic is executed by a few threads. The simulation logic threads both read and write from/to the simulation data structures.
- For each client there is a Java thread performing a blocking read call to the socket for that client. When a poll command is received from a client, the corresponding client thread reads info from the simulation data structures (one client poll would typically be interested in a small subset of the total data structures) and sends a reply to the client on the client's socket. Thus, access to the data structures would need to be synchronized between the client threads and the simulation threads (I would try to have the locks on smaller subsets of the data). If a control command is received from the client, the client thread would write to the data structures.

For small number of clients, I think this would work fine.

Question 1: Would this threading model hold for a large number (thousands) of connected clients? I'm not familiar with what memory/CPU overhead there would be in such a Java implementation.

Question 2: I would like to avoid having the server asynchronously send messages to the clients but in certain scenarios I may need to have the server send "update yourself now" messages asynchronously to some or many clients and I'm not quite sure how to do that. Having the simulation logic thread(s) send those messages doesn't seem right... maybe some "client notification thread pool" concept?

Comment: I doubt that anyone can answer re: "thousands of threads".  Push to client suggests web sockets to me.  This design sounds complex to me.  Multi-threaded code is hard to write, even for smart people.  It feels like you're doing it wrong if you're not using the new concurrency packages or map/reduce or something like MPI.  Can't tell without more details.

Comment: Architecture is a very broad subject and generally not a good fit here - this question would be better at the [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is for *specific* coding questions (e.g. implementing or troubleshooting a given part of said architecture).

Comment: Thanks duffymo I'll look into MPI. Yes, this design would mean thousands of simultaneous java threads (although each thread would be idle the vast majority of it's lifetime)

Comment: Aha, thanks brichins

Comment: I don't see how thousands of threads will be helpful on a single server.  More than one thread per core means you'll be context switching.  If your threads are long-lived I can see things bogging down.  If you have an executor pool, one per core, and short thread lifetimes per request it'll work.

Comment: I agree - it won't help at all. But I'm not sure how to handle reading from multiple sockets within one thread in Java? I've seen something called "NIO" mentioned. Is there any best practice for reading from multiple sockets?

Comment: @brichins when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: After some further investigation it seems to me that Java NIO, possibly with some higher abstraction layer like Netty, is the way to go. By using the non-blocking NIO mechanisms it seems I should be able to handle a large amount of client sockets from within one or a few threads in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You ask two questions; I'll answer the first.

I've previously written an application that involved thousands of threads in one application.  We did once run into a problem with the maximum number of threads on the Linux server; for us, I think the limit was about 1000 threads.  This affected our Java application because Java threads use native threads.  We set the limit higher, and the application scaled to about 2000 threads, which was what we needed without an issue; I don't know what would have happened had we needed to scale it much higher.

The fact that the default maximum number of threads was 1000 suggests that it might not be wise to run too many thousands of threads on a single Linux server.  I believe the primary issue is that sufficient memory for a stack needs to be allocated for each thread.

Our intended long term fix was to change to an architecture where threads from a thread pool each serviced multiple sockets.  This really isn't too much of an issue; for each socket, the thread just has to process any pending messages before going on to the next socket.  You would have to be careful about synchronizing memory access, but your application already needs to do that since your simulation interacts with multiple threads already so that part would not be a huge change.

Comment: Thanks Warren. As I just wrote in a comment to my original post it seems your proposal is the way to go, probably by using Java NIO to handle multiple sockets from within one thread.